# Determine if a list contain list

Tags: lisp

I want to check if a list in LISP contains list or not recursively. How to fix this code?

```
(defun has-list-p(l)
     (if null l)
          nil
          (and (listp(car l)) (has-list-p(l))))
```

Thanks all! The solution I coded is:

```
(defun has-list-p(l)
  (if (null l)
      nil
      (or (listp(car l)) (has-list-p(cdr l)))))
```

Comment: Spaces aside, that's exactly the same code I wrote. My hat is off to you for actually solving the problem yourself. Well done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to give you the code, though I've written it. I will tell you what you've done wrong, though:

- Check the line `(if null l)`. You're missing a paren.
- Are you sure `and` is comparator you want?
- You're calling `has_list_p` recursively, which is correct, but you want to call it on the *rest* of the list -- all but the first element. How might you get that?

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: lol, I was just about to post an answer with the code, but I like your approach much better :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun has-list-p(l)
  ;nothing more to check - return nil - no inner lists
  (if (null l)
  nil
  ;the first element of the list is a list?
  (if (listp (car l))
      ;if yes - return true
      t
      ;otherwise - try for the cdr of the list
   (has-list-p (cdr l)))))
```

In common lisp after I defined this procedure, it printed:

```
[2]> (has-list-p '(1 2))
NIL
[3]> (has-list-p '(1 2 '(3 4)))
T
```

The same in Emacs Lisp.